# Unit test fail when result type is tile

Tags: unit-testing, junit, struts2, tiles

I am trying to test my action classes with the jUnit plugin. The action looks like this:

```
@Action(value = "default", results = {
    @Result(name = "success", type="tiles", location = "login") })
public String defaultAction() {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I call the `proxy.execute()`, the test crashes. I am probably forgetting
something that makes my test run with tiles, but i have no clue about what that may be.
I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
...
```

When I change the action as below, the test executes normally:

```
@Action(value = "default", results = {
    @Result(name = "success", type="redirectAction", location = "login") })
public String defaultAction() {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You might try looking at line 105 in TilesResult to see what would cause an NPE there.

Comment: `TilesContainer container = TilesAccess.getContainer(servletContext); ... container.render(location, request, response);` The `container` is null. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before `proxy.execute()`, the `executeResult` should be set `false` value: `proxy.setExecuteResult(false)`.

Comment: The answer at "[npe-in-strutstestcase-after-enabling-tiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823709/npe-in-strutstestcase-after-enabling-tiles#9062291)" shows how to setup junit and tiles to get past the NPE